# R function to save posthoc test results in dataframe

Tags: r

Hi guys I am running a statistical test with a follow up of a Dunnetts-Test using this code:

```
dun_4h_noS9 <- DunnettTest(x=fourh_noS9_table$MN_rate, g=fourh_noS9_table$Dose, control ="0")
```

which works great and I get the output:

```
Dunnett's test for comparing several treatments with a control :  
    95% family-wise confidence level

$`0`
                  diff  lwr.ci  upr.ci   pval    
0.01-0          0.0667 -1.9119  2.0452 1.0000    
0.03-0          0.0167 -1.9619  1.9952 1.0000    
0.08-0         -0.0667 -2.0452  1.9119 1.0000    
0.25-0         -0.0333 -2.0119  1.9452 1.0000    
0.74-0          0.2222 -1.7563  2.2008 1.0000    
2.22-0          1.2833 -0.6952  3.2619 0.3704    
6.67-0          6.6056  4.6270  8.5841 <2e-16 ***
20-0           28.8853 26.9067 30.8639 <2e-16 ***
Mitomycin C -0 12.6833 10.7048 14.6619 <2e-16 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

When trying to save that list to a tibble I keep loosing the Information about which groups were compared in the test and also the significancies ( which is not that much of a problem):

```
tibble <- map(dun_4h_noS9,~data.frame(.))
tibble<-map_dfr(tibble,~mutate_all(.,as.character))
```

Output:

```
 diff  lwr.ci  upr.ci   pval
1  0.0667 -1.9119  2.0452      1
2  0.0167 -1.9619  1.9952      1
3 -0.0667 -2.0452  1.9119      1
4 -0.0333 -2.0119  1.9452      1
5  0.2222 -1.7563  2.2008      1
6  1.2833 -0.6952  3.2619 0.3704
7  6.6056   4.627  8.5841      0
8 28.8853 26.9067 30.8639      0
9 12.6833 10.7048 14.6619      0
```

Does a way exist where I can keep the infos about the group comparissons?

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you could save the results with:

```
test_df <- data.frame(dun_4h_noS9$`0`)

test_df$comparisons <- row.names(test_df)
```

This stores the results as a data frame then creates a new column called *comparisons* since the comparisons are stored as the row names. Consider providing a reproducible answer to get a faster more reliable answer.